# Sending email id as a parameter to javascript function: Syntax Error illegal character

Tags: javascript, html

I'm stuck with some JavaScript code, i want to send an email id to a js function using onclick function. While sending the email id to the function, the firebug shows the error saying **SyntaxError: illegal character** at the "@" character below is the snippet of my HTML and JavaScript code.
Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!!

HTML

```
 <button onclick="myFunction("xyz@abc.com")">Click me!</button>
```

JavaScript

```
 function myFunction(email){ //error at this line for @ character
    alert(email);
 }
```

Comment: FYI : [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Answer (score 4):

You are unintentionally closing your `"` (double quote):

```
<button onclick="myFunction("xyz@abc.com")">Click me!</button>
```

Should be something like this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction('xyz@abc.com')">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes `'` for the string

```
onclick="myFunction('xyz@abc.com')"
```